# why EnvInject plugin doesn't capture the new env variable after the build?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have an analysis number variable in my batch script that increments after every job build. I have to get this new value in my post build email notification. I have configured well the EnvInject plugin to get my variable.
When I look into the generated log file 'injectedEnvVars.txt' I keep getting the same initial variable value (ex. 85) even though my analysis number environment variable has incremented (ex. 90). why EnvInject doesn't capture the new env variable after the build ?

Comment: Those environment variables simply are not global (or "saved" afterwards), but only valid for the current job.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to make them global ? Thanks.

Comment: @StephenKing I am still struggling to solve this issue, any help from you would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q).